# How do I return the value pointed to by a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class member defined as:

```
someType* X;
```

and I get it like:

```
someType* getX() {return x;}
```

I would like to get the value rather than the pointer i.e.:

```
someType getX() {return x;} //this is wrong
```

what is the proper syntax for this? How do I get the value rather than the pointer?

Comment: You need to get a good C++ book, and **stop using pointers** until then (and probably for quite some time afterwards). Learn the basics of C++ first, pointers later (no, those are *not* the basics!).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
someType getX() {return *x;}
```

Note though that this returns `x` *by value*, i.e. it creates a copy of `x` at each return*. So (depending on what `someType` really is) you may prefer returning a *reference* instead:

```
someType& getX() {return *x;}
```

Returning by reference is advisable for non-primitive types where the cost of construction may be high, and implicit copying of objects may introduce subtle bugs.

*<sub>This may be optimized away in some cases by *return value optimization*, as @paul23 rightly points out below. However, the safe behaviour is not to count on this in general. If you don't ever want an extra copy to be created, make it clear in the code for both the compiler and human readers, by returning a reference (or pointer).</sub>

Comment: -Obligatory note about return value optimizations though-. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.9

Comment: Returning by mutable reference has different semantics, though.

Comment: @paul23, thanks for mentioning, I added a footnote to elaborate.

Comment: @larsmans, different from returning by value indeed, but similar to returning by mutable pointer, which the OP is after.

Answer (score 2):

```
someType getX() const { return *x; }
```

or alternatively, if `someType` is expensive to copy, return it by `const` reference:

```
someType const &getX() const { return *x; }
```

Note that `const` qualifier on the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeType getX()
{
  //  SomeType x = *x; // provided there is a copy-constructor if    
  //  user-defined type.
  // The above code had the typo. Meant to be.
  SomeType y = *x;
   return y;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this ? There is a performance problem here, but it serves the purpose of the question.

Comment: Sorry typo there. Meant to be SomeType y = *x; return y;